# Android GPS Proximity Alert when starting within the set proximity

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, proximity

I would like to use Android's Proximity Alert for my garage door app.  I have a button setup, that when pressed add's the proximity alert and starts tracking location.  I want it to track indefinitely until I either enter or exit the proximity.  If entering it will open the garage door, if exiting it will close the garage door after which I remove the proximity alert and GPS shuts off.  I have it working close to perfectly.

The problem is, when I press the button while in my driveway, hence in the proximity, the intent always fires immediately with the extra KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING set to "entering".  If I start the tracking outside of the proximity, it acts as expected, only fires once I enter the proximity.  How can I get exiting the proximity when starting inside of it working in the same manner?  Thanks in advance, here's my code.

In my activity:

```
float radius = 100f;
double lat = 37.422;
double lon = -122.084;

// Expiration is 10 Minutes
long expiration = 600000;

LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(proximityIntentAction);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);
```

And here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.v("SomeTag","Proximity Alert Intent Received");
    String direction = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    CharSequence text = direction;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "going: "+text, duration);
    toast.show();
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    locManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.
In the past it worked for me as your would expect, if registering proximity while im out of the proximity was getting fired immediately with isEntering=false now, it not firing at all. ---- i just need to know if its device specific or from a certain android version.

Answer (score 2):

why not put a timer/delay on the firing of the button? For example, why not allow yourself a fixed amount of time to get out of the proximity before your app starts detecting? I think that many home alarms work in the same way. Or, another option might be to detect and ignore your first entry into the proximity and validate any subsequent re-entries to that proximity (i.e. your garage). What do you think?

Comment: Thats a great suggestion. I've also picked up a delay when ever i start up a the proximity alert...