# proximity alert firing at wrong time

Tags: android, notifications, gps, alert

my code uses gps coordinates to locate and save the location.

when the person enters the area, it should create a notification and alert.

problem: 
when the user saves the location, it sends an alert instantly, which i assume is wrong.

how can I solve it ? thanks

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

WemoActivity wemo = new WemoActivity();


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {



        Toast.makeText(context,"in the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Entering");

        try { wemo.SWITCHON();} catch (Exception e){ //throw new RuntimeException(e); 

            }


    }
    else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exiting");
         Toast.makeText(context,"out of the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



         try { wemo.SWITCHOFF();} catch (Exception e){ //throw new RuntimeException(e); 

        }
    }

    sendNotification(context);



}


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void sendNotification(Context context){
        // String extra=arg1.getExtras().getString("alert").toString();
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String message = "You are near your office/home.";

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,message, when);

        String title = "Proximity Alert!"; 

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;


        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);



        return;


    }




}
```

Comment: Please post your code that sends the alert.

Answer (score 1):

There is some good info on this exact issue here: [Android GPS Proximity Alert when starting within the set proximity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556314/android-gps-proximity-alert-when-starting-within-the-set-proximity)

I would think a good solution is the simple approach of setting a flag when the user saves the location, and ignore any `entering` broadcasts until the device has left the area for the first time.

Something like this:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public boolean firstSet = false;  //Set this to true when user initially saves location

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

WemoActivity wemo = new WemoActivity();


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if (entering) {

      if (!firstSet){

        Toast.makeText(context,"in the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Entering");

        try { wemo.SWITCHON();} catch (Exception e){ //throw new RuntimeException(e); 

            }
       }

    }
    else {
       if (!firstSet){
         Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exiting");
         Toast.makeText(context,"out of the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         try { wemo.SWITCHOFF();} catch (Exception e){ //throw new RuntimeException(e); 
         }

       }
       else{
          firstSet = false;
       }

    }

    sendNotification(context);

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I have changed my code to the one you gave me but nothing changed. do I need to change anything else or in any other class so it would work ? Im a beginner :)

Comment: This was just to give you an idea of the logic.  You might want to try saving the state in SharedPreferences, so that you can read the state everywhere on your code.